# Excessive spa bath foam when cleaning

Tags: cleaning, bathtub

We've recently renovated this bathroom, and since our Spa Bath hasn't been used in quite some time we decided to give it a clean out. We used [Pure-Spa Whirlpool Cleaner & Degreaser](http://www.hydrospares.co.uk/whirlpool-spares/care-maintenance/cleaning-additives/whirlpool-cleaning/pure-spa-whirlpool-cleaner-degreaser-plumbing-system-cleaner-various-pack-size.htm?opt=23&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjYai-Y761gIV6rDtCh0PgQAnEAQYASABEgLXiPD_BwE) and followed the instructions precisely.

Our bath doesn't allow us to shut the air off completely however we do turn it to minimum, along with the pump intensity.

So I turned the bath on, went downstairs to make some food. I was gone for ~2-5 minutes however that was time enough, I came back up and before I entered the room I saw my room had been taken over by bubbles.  They were cascading over the edge of the bath and were now stacking up on the floor! In this time they had already become knee deep, coming up to the same height of the toilet. They were not easy to neutralize, in the end we had to pick them up and move them away.

I read that this cleaner can cause some foaming, however i do honestly believe this is excessive. (Attached is an image of the second run which I left on for 10 seconds after cleaning the mess up)
[image: Bath full of foam]

How can I prevent this massive amount of froth from occurring and is there any good method for neutralizing it fast when it does?

Comment: Fur future reference, many aerosols (like deoderant, air freshener, etc) will knock those bubbles down quickly.

Comment: OMG thanks, i just went into the other room to try this, and it works a charm! The chemicals in the deodorant won't cause any negative affects on what's going on in the bath i presume?

Comment: As to what caused it: probably too much cleaner, you're going to have to experiment a bit on what the right amount is for your bath.

Comment: pool and hot tub stores sell a defoaming spray that works great. As far as cleaning @David moritz has it right but not enough info. Dishwasher soap is great, it sanatizes the tub and will not foam (we used this on a commercial 8 tub location when changing the water weekly). Ask any kid that used regular soap like dawn in a dishwasher what happens (the same or worse than your experience). Coming out of the drains.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you *didn't* follow the directions precisely.

> Some foaming will occur so **never leave unattended**, always close the air valve/turn to minimum whilst the whirlpool system is running.

Had you been watching you would've surely paused the cycle to let the foam subside, then continue as necessary. A good rinse afterward completes the job.

Answer (score 0):

Use powdered dishwasher soap its all the same as the cleaner packs sold by the major tub suppliers.

Comment: Powdered dish detergent is notoriously harsh--it even tends to etch glass. I would not use it for cleaning bath fixtures.

Comment: Well better tell Jacuzzi then because the expensive Jacuzzi detergent packs sold to clean their equipment is the exact the same chemically

Comment: You might mention that in your answer (along with some supporting references). No one should take a bare assertion like you provided as useful. I'm happy to change my mind if you improve.

Comment: Also, the solution in this particular case is not to buy more products. It's to use what has already been purchased _properly_.